# How to resolve an async function from within a settimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I write this code using async, await only:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
 setTimeout(() => {
   resolve(‘done’)
 }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. What `async` and `await` do is they can replace `.then`s, eg:

```
function foo(someProm) {
  return someProm.then(() => {
    console.log('someProm done');
  });
}
```

can turn into

```
async function foo(someProm) {
  await someProm;
  console.log('someProm done');
}
```

They can also automatically wrap their return value in a Promise if the return value is synchronous - eg

```
async function foo() {
  return '2';
}
```

will return a Promise which resolves to 2.

But `async` and `await` *cannot* replace the generic Promise constructor. If you have a callback-based API, and you want a Promise that resolves when the callback finishes, you can't use `async` and `await` for that task - you *must* use `new Promise` as you're doing here.

---

There's one exception which is barely worth mentioning, and should not be used. In the particular case of `setTimeout`, when nothing else needs to be done between the time the Promise is created and when it resolves, it's theoretically possible to create an `async` function which *blocks* for however many seconds you need, and then resolves:

```js
console.log('start');

// Putting this in a setTimeout so that "start" logs above
// before the below code starts blocking
setTimeout(() => {
  const theProm = (async () => {
    const t0 = performance.now();
    while (performance.now() - t0 < 1000);
  })();

  theProm.then(() => {
    console.log('done');
  });
}, 100);
```

(For informational purposes only. Do not use that code)